# есть h1 input button во время клика на кнопку нужно увеличить число в h1 который был введён в input

Tags: javascript

```js
function pribavit(){
    let y = +inp.value;
   result.innerHTML = + y+parseInt(result)
    
     
}
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
      <title>Document</title>
 </head>
 <body class="container">
     <div class="text-center">
          <h1 id="result">0</h1>
      <input id="inp">
     <button onclick="pribavit()">+</button> 
      </div>
  </body>
 </html>
```

есть h1, input, button во время клика на кнопку нужно что бы число ноль внутри h1 увеличился на число, записанное в input

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
function pribavit() {
  let y = +inp.value;
  if (!isNaN(y))
    result.textContent = +result.textContent + y;
}
```

```html
<div class="text-center">
  <h1 id="result">0</h1>
  <input id="inp">
  <button onclick="pribavit()">+</button>
</div>
```