# как определить чётное число или нет

Tags: javascript

```js
let x = 0;
function pribavit(){
    x++;
    result.innerHTML = x;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="result">0</h1>
     <button onclick="pribavit()" >+</button>
```

когда нажимаешь на кнопку плюсует еденицу, нужно чтобы при нечётном число было красным а при чётном зелёным

Comment: Вы вот здесь ничего не забыли сделать? - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1074144

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
let x = 0;
function pribavit() {
  x++;
  result.innerHTML = x;
  result.style.color = x % 2? "red" : "green";
}
```

```html
<h1 id="result">0</h1>
<button onclick="pribavit()">+</button>
```